# To change short to color or other way round

Tags: java, colors

How do I change the color type to short or short to color?
Actually, I am using setFillForegroundColor method of  HSSFCellStyle class.
And I need to pass color to my method and use the function.
But, it takes short type as object.
Is there some way that I can change it to my required type or is there some other method which can help me setting the foreground color?

As I am fetching the color from user preference, so I don't know the color previously.
So, I can not use color index.
Please suggest me something.
My code looks like this:

```
private void setBackgroudColorOfRow(HSSFWorkbook wb, HSSFRow row, Color bgColor) {
            HSSFCell cell;
            //Iterate through each cell and colour with light orange to 
            //differentiate the summary row with detail rows
            for (Iterator it = row.cellIterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                cell = (HSSFCell) it.next(); // row.getCell(j);
                if(cell.getColumnIndex() > 1)
                {
                    HSSFCellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
                    style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);  
                    style.setFillForegroundColor(bgColor);
```

OK, let me re-frame my question or rather shorten it:

How do I get color code index if I have the color code in string or rather I have color name, how would I get its color code index?

Answer (score 1):

style.setRightBorderColor(HSSFColor.BLACK.index);

Please see this to deal with custom colors.

http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CustomColors

---

//creating a custom palette for the workbook
    HSSFPalette palette = wb.getCustomPalette();

```
//replacing the standard red with freebsd.org red
palette.setColorAtIndex(HSSFColor.RED.index,
        (byte) 153,  //RGB red (0-255)
        (byte) 0,    //RGB green
        (byte) 0     //RGB blue
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer But I Need to fill the foreground With the user chosen color. For that i need index for the color which user had chosen. And this method will set right border color. and also this is for static color like black. I need a method which return me the index of the color which has been passed by user

Comment: Thanks a lot dear. But still in that code Colors are hard coded. I just want a method which can take up a variable of color type and return me the index of that color.

Comment: updated answer again, that is as far as I know, I understand what you are asking, but that is my best guess... I will have to search for some code, if I find it I will update this link.

Comment: Thanks buddy, but i guess igot the code, actually i got rgb combi of the color. And then with the help of **HSSFColor object = palette.findSimilarColor(b1, b2, b3)  'short index = object.getIndex();' ** Igot the index of my color. My problem is solved. And thanks a lot for ur answer and pain u took

Comment: cool... update your question with your solution. That is good for others to solve. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
private Short getColorIndex(String colorStr, HSSFWorkbook wb) {
       //in this method string containing RGB component is passed
       //and corresponding color index is obtained and returned. 
       short index = 0;
       String[] rgb = colorStr.split(",");
       System.out.println(colorStr+"--------------");

       Integer red = Integer.parseInt(rgb[0]);
       Integer green = Integer.parseInt(rgb[1]);
       Integer blue = Integer.parseInt(rgb[2]);

       palette = wb.getCustomPalette();
       HSSFColor color = palette.findSimilarColor(red, green, blue);
       if(color != null){
            index = color.getIndex();
       }
       else{
           index = IndexedColors.LIME.getIndex();
       }
       return index;
    }
```

This method returned me index of my color. Although it is fulfilling my requirement but still i am not getting my exact color. If somebody could suggest anything. otherwise it working fine. And also findColor(byte,byte,byte) returns same thing.

Apart from that u can also change 'int' to 'byte' if u want to use findColor(byte,byte,byte) method